# Calling a basic LSTM cell within a custom Tensorflow cell

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement the MATCH LSTM from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.07905.pdf

I'm using Tensorflow. One part of the architecture is an RNN that uses the input and the previous state to compute an attention vector which it applies to a context before concatenating the result with the inputs and sending them into an LSTM. To build the first part of this RNN, I wrote a custom cell for Tensorflow to call. But I'm not sure how to send the results into an LSTM. Is it possible to call the basic LSTM cell within the custom cell I'm writing? I tried this a few different ways but kept getting the error "module' object has no attribute 'rnn_cell'" at the line where the LSTM cell is called. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT to add code:

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class MatchLSTMCell(tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell):

```
def __init__(self, state_size, question_tensor, encoded_questions, batch_size):
    self._state_size = state_size
    self.question_tensor = question_tensor
    self.encoded_questions = encoded_questions
    self.batch_size = batch_size

@property
def state_size(self):
    return self._state_size

@property
def output_size(self):
    return self._state_size

def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    scope = scope or type(self).__name__

    with tf.variable_scope(scope):

        W_p = tf.get_variable("W_p", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.state_size, self.state_size], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        W_r = tf.get_variable("W_r", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.state_size, self.state_size], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        b_p = tf.get_variable("b_p", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.state_size])
        w = tf.get_variable("w", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[1,self.state_size])
        b = tf.get_variable("b", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[])

        #print 'question tensor', np.shape(self.question_tensor)
        #print 'inputs', np.shape(inputs)
        #print 'insides', np.shape(tf.matmul(inputs, W_p) + tf.matmul(state, W_r) + b_p)
        G = tf.nn.tanh(
                       tf.transpose(tf.transpose(self.question_tensor, perm=[1,0,2]) + 
                       (tf.matmul(inputs, W_p) + tf.matmul(state, W_r) + b_p), perm=[1,0,2])
                       )
        #print 'big G', np.shape(G)

        attention_list = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            attention_matrix = tf.matmul(G[i,:,:], tf.transpose(w))
            attention_list.append(attention_matrix)
        attention_scores = tf.stack(attention_list)
        a = tf.nn.softmax(attention_scores + b)
        a = tf.reshape(a, [self.batch_size, -1])
        #print 'a shape is', np.shape(a)

        weighted_question_list = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            attention_vector = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(a[i], [1,-1]), self.encoded_questions[i])
            weighted_question_list.append(attention_vector)
        weighted_questions = tf.stack(weighted_question_list)
        weighted_questions = tf.reshape(weighted_questions, [32, -1])
        #print'weighted questions', np.shape(weighted_questions)

        z = tf.concat([inputs, weighted_questions], 1)
        lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.state_size)
        output, new_state = lstm_cell.__call__(z, state)

    return output, new_state
```

Comment: Without code to look at this is difficult and I'd like to help.  What would help you is to create a minimalistic test program that shows that your custom RNN works or doesn't work and another minimalistic test of how you are using LSTM and if that works or doesn't.  Those same two programs would help others (including me) on stack overflow help you debug your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll get to writing those programs. I added my code to the post in case it could be helpful until I can write those programs. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to reimplement Match_LSTM for Squad for experiment.
I use [MurtyShikhar's](https://github.com/MurtyShikhar/Question-Answering) as reference. It works! However, he had to customize AttentionWrapper and use existed BasicLSTM cell.

I also try to create a Match_LSTM_cell by putting z and state as (inputs,state) pair in [Basic_LSTM](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/927f811b0303e51126531c135f8b093383de2d6d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L374):

```
    def __call__(self, inputs,state):
        #c is not a output. c somehow is a "memory keeper".
        #Necessary to update and pass new_c through LSTM
        c,h=state

        #...Calculate your z
        #...inputs will be each tokens in context(passage) respectively
        #...Calculate alpha_Q
        z=tf.concat([inputs,alpha_Q],axis=1)

        ########This part is reimplement of Basic_LSTM
        with vs.variable_scope("LSTM_core"):
            sigmoid=math_ops.sigmoid
            concat=_linear([z,h],dimension*4,bias=True)
            i,j,f,o=array_ops.split(concat,num_or_size_splits=4,axis=1)
            new_c=(c*sigmoid(f+self._forget_bias)+sigmoid(i)*self._activation(j))

            new_h = self._activation(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
            new_state=(new_c,new_h)
        return new_h,new_state
```